# How do I use JAXB @XmlValue on a subclass?

Tags: jaxb

I want XML like this:

```
<simple>Foo</simple>
```

I can do this successfully via a JAXB class that looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="simple")
class Simple {
    @XmlValue
    public String contents;
}
```

But now I need to make the Simple class be a subclass of another class like so:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="simple")
class Simple extends OtherClass {
    @XmlValue
    public String contents;
}
```

That fails with `@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.` I can't easily refactor the superclass away (because of the way we're using @XmlElementRef on a wrapper class). Is there a workaround that will let me annotate my subclass to generate that simple XML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

This use case is supported by MOXy, and IMHO should be supported by the JAXB RI as well:

**Simple**

This class has a field mapped with `@XmlValue` and extends `OtherClass`:

```
package forum809827;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlRootElement(name="simple")
class Simple extends OtherClass {

    @XmlValue
    // @XmlValueExtension
    // As of moxy 2.6, XmlValueExtension needs to be added for this to work
    public String contents;

}
```

**OtherClass**

This is the super class.  In MOXy the subclass can map a field/property with `@XmlValue` as long as the super class does not have any mappings to an XML element:

```
package forum809827;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class OtherClass {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String other;

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum809827;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Simple.class);

        Simple simple = new Simple();
        simple.contents = "FOO";
        simple.other = "BAR";

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(simple, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<simple xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" other="BAR">FOO</simple>
```

**For More Information on Specifying MOXy as Your JAXB Provider**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed example! Unfortunately, my app container (Karaf) uses jaxb-impl/jaxb-xjc from ServiceMix and it would be difficult to switch, I believe.

Comment: @ChrisDolan - It depends on your application environment.  The JAXB provider can be configured at the model level.  In the following post MOXy is used in the GlassFish server that uses the JAXB RI by default:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

Comment: @ChrisDolan - When using the JAXB RI you may be able to mark `OtherClass` as being @XmlTransient:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html

Comment: I'm so tired of this everywhare `MOXy` placement. The question was about **pure** JAXB!

Comment: This solution does not work if you have an extra indirection. When I have abstract superclass (with marshall method) > abstract subclass > concrete subclass (with @XmlValue and @XmlValueExtension), I get the same error in OP while using MOXy.

Comment: I agree with Andremoniy, every time I look up JAXB I see "Blaise Doughan." If I want to hear about your personal project, I'll ask for it.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Everything is fine as described but I also needed to add the @XmlTransient to the superclass

Comment: I also had to add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` to my subclass, or I would get the error `If a class has '@XmlElement' property, it cannot have '@XmlValue' property.`. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work by changing `@XmlValue` to `@XmlMixed` and changing the variable to a list.  The resulting class should look like the following.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="simple")
class Simple extends OtherClass {
    @XmlMixed
    public List<String> contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me , and took me a little bit time.
Thanks to Blaise Doughan
I go through his blog and find the answer

1. you have to add a 
   jaxb.properties file with `javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`
   in the same package in order to use MOXy
2. add moxy to your maven dependency or add moxy jar

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.0</version>
   </dependency>`
3. then all set
   I have sample here you can go though my project and take a look at
   https://github.com/cicidi/HelloCCD/tree/master/Jaxb