# dbId="0" in jaxb XML Marshall for Entity's

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have  Entity Beans A,B with annotation @Entity 
When i try to marshall that Bean using JAXB Marshing I got an XML like structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a:A xmlns:a="..........." xmlns:b="...........">
<a:B dbId="0" >
<b:FirstName dbId="0">......</b:FirstName>
</a:B>
</a:A>
```

I have used

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A",namespace = "........")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) 
@Entity
public class A{
@XmlElement(name = "B")
    private B name;
............
...............
}

@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "B",namespace = "........")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) 
public class B{
.................
}
```

1. Why an I getting standalone="yes"  during marshall and how to remove this ?
2. Why am I getting dbId="0" and how can i remove it ?
3. How can I add the class="x.y.z.A" like thing in my attributes like following :

   ```
   <a:B class="x.y.z.B" >
   ```

I have a class which has only one variable of type "Float" , and i don't want to show the float in the xml .

```
@XmlRootElement(name="start")
public class Start extends Timing{

    private Float mFloat;

    public Float getFloat() {
        return mFloat;
    }

    public void setFloat(Float f) {
        mFloat = f;
    }

}
```

When i marshall it i get

```
<a:start>
            <start:float>8.329042</start:float>
        </a:start>
```

How can i show it without the "float tag" , like following ?

```
<a:start>8.329042<a/start>
```

For security reason I cannot provide my real classes .

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set the `JAXB_FRAGMENT` property on the `Marshaller` to prevent the header from being written to an `OutputStream` or `Writer`.
2. You must have a primitive numeric field/property annotated with `@XmlAttribute`.  JAXB won't marshal null values so you could change the primitive to its corresponding object form (I.e. `int` to `Integer`).
3. You could introduce a private static `String` field annotated with `@XmlAttribute` and populate it with this value.
4. You can annotate the `float` property with `@XmlValue` to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Blaise , but may be I missed some details :

Comment: 1. JAXB_FRAGMENT removes the whole <?xml ...> line , but i just want to remove standalone="yes" text and keep 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> like this

Comment: 4.I forgot to mention in the example that the   Start class has been derived from some other class , so I am getting this exception : @XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.
I have seen your answer of the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098274/how-do-i-use-jaxb-xmlvalue-on-a-subclass) , but it doesn't solve my problem